# Database for the chat page

Tags: database, singlestore

I plan to create a website with the ability to write with users in real time, I am looking for a suitable database that will be efficient. MemSQL was my favorite.
My question is how to configure the MemSQL database (master / slave) in such a way that in the future it can be easily scaled

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you require any special configuration  at this stage on client or MemSQL. Scaling/High availability is in architecture in MemSQL you can add more Server/Leaf nodes later.. may be you should look at nodejs [SocketCluster](https://socketcluster.io/#!/) for client load balancing